# Update textView from an item in a custom listView Android

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a custom listView with a textView, editText and a Button on a row. The listView is created with an adapter.
I want to update the textView with the value entered in editText when I press the button.
I want to do this without refreshing the entire list.
Any ideea how can I update only one row from the list?
Thanks!

To be more clear I'll provide the code:

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context myContext;

```
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        myContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return nameList.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.travelpassengers_item,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();              
            holder.ratingTv = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvTPRating);             

            holder.rateBtn = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnTPRate);
            holder.plusBtn = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
            holder.minusBtn = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
            holder.rateEt = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.etTPRating); 
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ratingTv.setText(rating[position] + "/10");

        holder.callBtn.setTag(phoneList[position]);

        holder.ratingBtn.setTag(ids[position]);
        holder.ratingDisableBtn.setTag(numberRates[position]);
        holder.ratingTv.setTag(rating[position]);
        holder.rateEt.setTag(position);         

        holder.rateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                        String id = holder.ratingBtn.getTag().toString();
                        int position = Integer.parseInt(holder.rateEt
                                .getTag().toString());
                        double oldRate = Double
                                .parseDouble(rating[position]);
                        int number = numberRates[position];
                        double newRate = Double.parseDouble(holder.rateEt
                                .getText().toString());

                        DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat(
                                "#,##0.0");
                        number++;
                        double avg = (oldRate + newRate) / number;
                        newRate = Double.valueOf(oneDigit.format(avg));
                    // I want to put the value from newRate in the holder.ratingTv on right position without updating entire listView.                  

                }
            }
        });

        holder.plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int rate = Integer.parseInt(holder.rateEt.getText()
                        .toString());
                if (rate < 10) {
                    rate++;     
            holder.rateEt.setText(Integer.toString(rate));
                }
            }
        });

        holder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int rate = Integer.parseInt(holder.rateEt.getText()
                        .toString());
                if (rate > 0) {
                    rate--;         
        holder.rateEt.setText(Integer.toString(rate));
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {           
        public TextView  ratingTv;      
        public Button minusBtn, plusBtn;
        public EditText rateEt;
        public Button rateBtn;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getViewById(R.id.myTextView);
EditText et = (EditText) getViewById(R.id.myEditText);
Button b = (Button) getViewById(R.id.myButton);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.setText(et.getText());
    }
});
```

This may require some tweaking, as I haven't tested it out (such as a cast from CharSequence to String).

Comment: Make sure that you get the actual view that you want.  This approach may lead odd behavior since the same text view will be recycled over and over as the list scrolls.

Comment: I don't know how to get the actual view that I want to modify.

Comment: In your activity's onCreate method, there is a line, such as `setContentView(R.layout.main);` This is the line that sets the view of your activity. In this xml file (location in res/layout/main.xml), you should have your textview, edittext, and button. You can use the attribute `android:id` to set the name of the object (such as `android:id="@+id/myTextView"`)

Comment: Thank you, it was so easy! I thought I needed the position of the textview in lits to edit it value, but I don't. Thank you!