# ListItem onClick issue

Tags: android

I have a **listview** and in each of listitems I am adding a *checkbox*, two *textviews* and *imageview*. What I want is to have a click action on listitem and a separate click action on imageview as well (which lies in the listitem).
I used the following code for itemclick event :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(desserts.this);            // Used to show a dialog
            customizeDialog.show();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
```

Also on clicking item checkbox is checked. So, two things are happening (checkbox is checked and dialog appears), which is true according to functionality. I want that when user clicks the listitem checkbox is checked or unchecked and no dialog should appear, and when user click imageview on same listitem,only a dialog is shown above and no checkbox is checked or unchecked.
How can I achieve that? Please help.

Stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use an Adapter and set your listeners for your checkbox and dialog in the getView() of this adapter.

see: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

[Update textView from an item in a custom listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333764/update-textview-from-an-item-in-a-custom-listview-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I just tried the second link. It worked really fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

set the listener into the getView()

like for example:-

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
viewHolder.image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public voic onClick(View v){
             // do something here
        }
});
viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // do something
     }
});
view.setTag(viewHolder);
```